# how can I change the status bar icon color to white in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, statusbar

The status bar color should be black and its icons/texts colors should be white. But it is not working. Here is my code. Dear experts, please help me to solve it. Thank you.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0jif.png]

First Page image here.
[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXU97.png): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXU97.png][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXU97.png%5D%5B2%5D)

Comment: can you include your `FirstPage()`?

Comment: Sure. I've already added.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead,paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late but for those who face the same issue

Add the following code to `main.dart` in the `MaterialApp()` theme property

```
MaterialApp(
       theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
                  statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark, // For iOS: (dark icons)
                  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // For Android(M and greater): (dark icons)
                ))),
);
```

Noting that `Brightness.dark` provide dark icons and that's suitable for white background in black background case of course `Brightness.light`

That will work globally in your app

If you want it for a specific page, there's a property in `AppBar()` called `systemOverlayStyle:`
copy the same code above to it

```
AppBar(
    systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
                      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark, // For iOS: (dark icons)
                      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // For Android(M and greater): (dark icons)
                    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to use `systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,` to get white on android and rebuild the app.

> When set to [Brightness.light], the system navigation bar icons are light.
> When set to [Brightness.dark], the system navigation bar icons are dark.

```dart
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.black, // status bar color
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // Icon Color
      ),
    );
```

Comment: still, the status-bar icon color is not white using Brightness.dark or Brightness.light . Neither of them made any changes. Status bar still remains black. :(

Comment: did you reinstall/ rebuild the project ? also you can try `flutter clean` and then rebuild the project.

Comment: yes I did rebuild, also flutter clean. still it remains same. I don't even know why.

Comment: same here, must have been broken in flutter, absolutedly insane that we cant see status bar icons in a flutter app